# Why is this text not aligned vertically to my CSS grid row?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

My website will have information on the temperature and I am hoping to have a read out of temperature followed by a degree sign and either 'C' or 'F'.  There is other information on the page about the weather, so I am using CSS grid to layout the page and break all of the sections up.  When I make the degree note font size smaller, the degree moves higher on the page.  I would like it to be aligned with the temperature value, but I can't figure out whats going on in the page.  Any assistance would be amazing.

Photograph of the problematic text:

[image: Photograph of the Problematic Text]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.temp {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  padding: none;
  font-size: 3em;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.degree-note {
  font-size: 30px;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class='loading-text' src='img/weather-app-loading.png'>

  <div class='temp'>
    <h2 class='temp-degree'>34</h2>
    <h2 class='degree-note'>&deg C</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS flex-box** instead.
It's much more flexible and responsive than CSS grid.
Just run the code snippet you'll see.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.temp {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: none;
}

.temp-symbol {
  align-self: flex-start;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class='loading-text' alt="your image" src='img/weather-app-loading.png'>

  <h2 class='temp'>
    <span class='temp-number'>34</span>
    <span class='temp-symbol'>&deg C</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`H2` tag will break line. Use instead span tag to add a specific class to text.

```css
.wrapper {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 100px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}
.temp{ 
    position: relative;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
    padding: none;
    font-size: 3em;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.degree-note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    font-size: 30px;
    align-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <img class='loading-text' src='img/weather-app-loading.png'></img>

      <div class='temp'>
        <h2>
        <span class='temp-degree'>34</span>
        <span class='degree-note'>&deg C</span>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I get why you use span tags now.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Headings normally come with default margins. Remove those margins from your `h2` elements. That should get you where you want to go.

Then, for more precision, set an equal line height for the content.

Add this to your code:

```
.temp {
  line-height: 1;      /* inherits to children */
}

.temp-degree {
  margin: 0;           /* remove default margin */
  text-align: right;   /* optional; eliminates gap between elements */
}

.degree-note {
  margin: 0;           /* remove default margin */
}
```

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 100px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

.temp {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px;
  font-size: 3em;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1; /* inherits to children */
}

.temp-degree {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
  text-align: right;
}

.degree-note {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class='loading-text' src='img/weather-app-loading.png'>
  <div class='temp'>
    <h2 class='temp-degree'>34</h2>
    <h2 class='degree-note'>&deg C</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```